# Non significant Results in Calendar Anomaly study

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, finance

I am currently working on my Bachelor Thesis, but i'm running into some problems. Firstly, to sketch the situation, this is what my thesis is about:

I am testing to see if calendar anomalies have decreased over time in Europe. For this i have gathered the daily returns of four major stock indices from 1990 until now. My plan is to test whether or not the weekend effect exists and if it is declining over time, as well as three other calendar effects.

Now here is my problem. When running my regression of the day-of-the-week effect, absolutely no significant results come out, as well as my R squared is basically 0.

The regression i'm running is the following:

$R_t= β_1D$<sub>Mon</sub> +  $β_2D$<sub>Tue</sub> + $β_3D$<sub>Wed</sub> + $β_4D$<sub>Thur</sub> + $β_5D$<sub>Fri</sub> + $ϵ_t$

The dummy variables are for the days of the week, monday to friday.

Am i making some mistakes on the way, as it seems that for each index i run this test on, i seem to get similar results (non of which are significant).

EDIT:

When replacing extreme observations with a maxiumum of the mean plus 3 times the standard deviation (or the mean minus three times the standard deviation), the same problem arises. I have also been controlling for heteroskedasticity as well as autocorrelation where necesarry.

Comment: Do you only have 5 days I.e., Monday thru Friday in your data ? If so, you have to drop one of the days in your regression because using dummy variables for all the 5 days cause perfect multicollinearity and that might caus regression to fail.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified this, I am running a regression without a constant term, allowing for all five dummy variables to be in the regression.

Comment: The gradual but early vanishing (or, worse yet, reversal) of a day-of-week effect could swamp the signal you are looking for.  Ultimately you might need to resort to time series models, but one simple model you ought to consider evaluating early in your investigation would be the generalization that includes the interaction terms between a time variable and the day-of-week indicators. If a simple version of that shows promise, consider using a spline of the time variable. All this can be done graphically: you're basically smoothing five separate time series.